# How to disable MUI Blur effect on Menu dropdown?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to disable Material-UI blur effect when a user opens a dropdown(select menu). maybe it's a nice effect for only one input, but imagine a form with 20 dropdowns and every time user clicks one of them the entire screen blur and becomes noisy and unhandy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can ovverride mui styles with MUI [createTheme](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#createtheme-options-args-theme).

For my react application when I deleted this styles ovverride, the blur effect disappeared
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcp82.png)

you can just replace the blur with none

```
 MuiBackdrop: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      backdropFilter: 'none',

      '&.MuiBackdrop-invisible': {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        backdropFilter: 'none'
      }
    }
  }
},
```

you can read more here: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/